# AWS DynamoDB schema validation errors for List of Maps

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to store metadata emails that come from SES emails, specifically the "From" and "To" fields. After using a library to parse the MIME format, the fields look like arrays of maps:

From: [ { address: 'someone@company.com', name: 'The Person' } ]

To: [ { address: 'ok@aplace.com', name: '' } ]

My code for storing in dynamo sets up the putItem parameters like this:

```
var params = {
  "TableName": 'Emails',
  "Item" : {
  "from": {"L": mail_object.from },
  "subject": {"S": mail_object.subject },
  "to": {"L": mail_object.to},
  "html": {"S": mail_object.html},
  "text": {"S": mail_object.text},
 }
```

Note I just describe "from" and "to" as Lists. Then in a Lambda I do a putItem to store this data. But CloudWatch shows the following validation errors:

[MultipleValidationErrors: There were 4 validation errors:

UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'address' found in params.Item.L[0]

UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'name' found in params.Item.L[0]

UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'address' found in params.Item.L[0]

UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'name' found in params.Item.L0]

I assume this is an error in how I describe the schema. How should I describe the schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map has to be valid DynamoDB JSON, not standard JSON. Like this:

`[{M: { address: {S: 'ok@aplace.com'}, name: {S: ''} }}]`

A good way to see what this should look like is to create an entry in your table manually, via the console, then view the entry as Text and click the "DynamoDB JSON" checkbox to see what the DynamoDB format looks like.